# Name field to be exempted from replication in a panel

Tags: survey, surveyjs

Name field to be exempted from replication in a panel in surveyjs.
I am replicating all the fields of a panel but in that i need one field to be exampted.
I am replicating all the fields of a panel but in that i need one field to be exampted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.